# Why every strict stationary process have the following representation

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a strict stationary process, that is for every $n$, $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ and $(X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1})$ have the same distribution.

Then there is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, a r.v. $X$ and a measure-preserving transformation $T$ on $\Omega$ such that $X_n(\omega)= X(T^n(\omega))$ holds for all $n$.

I wonder why this is true when the $\{X_n\}$ have there values in a Polish space. can anyone explain this? Does the Kolmogorov extension theorem applies?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(S,d)$ be the Polish space where the $X_n$ take their values. Let $f\colon \Omega\to S^{\Bbb N_0}$ be defined by $f(\omega):=(X_n(\omega),n\geqslant 1)$. There is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(A):=P\{\omega,f(\omega)\in A\}$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(S^{\Bbb N_0})$. Let $T\colon S^{\Bbb N_0}\to S^{\Bbb N_0}$ defined by $T((x_n,n\geqslant 1))=(x_{n+1},n\geqslant 1)$. Then $T$ preserves $\mu$.

Comment: This yields $X$ and $T$ such that the **distributions** of the sequences $(X\circ T^n)_n$ and $(X_n)_n$ coincide (which is the reason why the statement in the question should be modified).

Comment: And of course: +1.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I want to know where the prerequisite "polish space" works.

Comment: It's a convenient choice, for example when we deal with product Borel $\sigma$-algebras (the most important is separability rather than completeness). A discussion about usefulness of Polish spaces in probability theory can be found here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20919/polish-spaces-in-probability.

Comment: @Did: Are you sure the condition "Polish space" is just a convenient choice, not meant to make the Kolmogorov extension theorem applicable? In Durrett's book "Probability theory and examples" pp 334 he requires the polish condition to apply the KET,but I can't see why. I also think your argument suffice.

Comment: lapuda: Your last comment is addressed to @DavideGiraudo, not me.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Would you please check my last comment? The "polish space" condition is not essentially used in your argument, but as far as I have seen in many books and notes such as Durrett's, they do emphasized on this prerequisite.

Comment: I'm sorry, I poorly expressed the idea. In "Polish", what matters is not completeness, it's separability. Indeed, it gives a characterization of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a countable product, which wouldn't necessarily hold in the case of non-separable metric spaces.

Comment: @lapuda One needs a theorem to ensure the existence of the measure $\mu$ in David's answer. For instance Kolmogorov's consistency theorem under the Polish assumption.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The mapping $\Omega\rightarrow (R^\infty,\mathcal{B}^\infty)$ is always measurable, so it pushes the probability measure on $\Omega$ to a probability measure on $R^\infty$. This argument does not involve Kolmogorov's theorem. Is there something missing?

Comment: @lapuda That sounds right but they are some points to check: measurability of $f$ and the fact that the coordinates process has the same finite-dimensional distributions as $(X_n)$. I have not tried to do this exercise.