# Convergence of series of expectations of indicator functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, ergodic-theory

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of stationary ergodic random variables. Let $A$ be an event such that $p = P(X_1\in A)>0$.

**Question:** Does the following series converge:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}E\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k}1_{\{X_n\in A\}}\right).
\end{align}

**Notes:** The potential difficulty lies in the stationary ergodicness instead of independence. If $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an iid sequence, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}E\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k}1_{\{X_n\in A\}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k}E\left(1_{\{X_n\in A\}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k}p = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^k<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Just by curiosity: in which context did this problem arise?

Comment: Im in time series econometrics and I'm trying to approach one stochastic process by a sequence of stochastic processes. Expanding backwards such an approximation process leads to these expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [the representation of a stationary sequence by dynamical systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366612/why-every-strict-stationary-process-have-the-following-representation), the question is equivalent to the following one.

> Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu,T\right)$ be an ergodic dynamical system, let $A\in\mathcal A$ such that $\mu\left(A\right)\lt 1$ and let $p_n:=\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nT^{-i}A\right)$. Is the sequence $\left(p_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ summable?

What is true is that $p_n\to 0$. Indeed, let $B:=\bigcap_{i\geqslant 1}T^{-i}A$. Then one can check that the sets $ T^{-l}\left(B\Delta T^{-1}B\right)$, $l\geqslant 1$ are pairwise disjoint, hence $\mu\left(B\Delta T^{-1}B\right)=0$. By ergodicity, $\mu\left(B\right)=0$.

However, it may be not true that the sequence $\left(p_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is summable. We shall use a variation of Lemma 3. 9 in [Lesigne, Emmanuel; Volný, Dalibor 
Large deviations for martingales. (English summary)
Stochastic Process. Appl. 96 (2001), no. 1, 143–159](http://ams.u-strasbg.fr/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=lesigne&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=26&mx-pid=1856684).

> **Lemma.** Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu,T\right)$ be an aperiodic dynamical system. Let $\left(n_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be an increasing sequence of integers and $\left(\delta_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ a sequence of numbers in $(0,1)$ such that for any $k\geqslant 1$, 
>   $$\tag{*}n_k\sum_{l\gt k}\delta_l\leqslant \frac 1{16}\delta_k.$$
>   Then there exists pairwise disjoint set $A_k$, $k\geqslant 1$ such that for any $k\geqslant 1$, $\mu\left(A_k\right)\leqslant \delta_k$ and $\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n_k}T^{-i}A_k\right)\geqslant \delta_k/2$.

*Sketch of proof.* For each $k$, by Rokhlin's lemma, there exists a set $B_k\in\mathcal A$ such that 
$$\frac{3}{16}\frac{\delta_k}{n_k}\leqslant \mu\left(B_k\right)\leqslant \frac{1}{4}\frac{\delta_k}{n_k}$$ 
and the sets $T^{-i}B_k$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant 4n_k$ are pairwise disjoint. Then define $C_k:=\bigcup_{j=1}^{4n_k}T^{-j}B_k$ and finally let $A_k:=C_k\setminus \bigcup_{l\gt k}C_l$.

- Since $\mu\left(C_k\right)\leqslant \delta_k$, we have $\mu\left(A_k\right)\leqslant\delta_k$.
- Pairwise disjointness follows by definition.
- We have 
  $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n_k}T^{-i}A_k\right) \geqslant \mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n_k}T^{-i}C_k\right)-n_k\sum_{l\gt k}\mu\left(C_l\right)$$
  and using $(*)$ and the inclusion $\bigcup_{j=n_k+1}^{4n_k}T^{-j}B_k\subset\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_k}T^{-j}C_k$, we get the third property.

---

Now, let $A:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ and let $\delta_k:=1/n_k$. Then we have to find an increasing sequence of integers $\left(n_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that $16n_k^2\sum_{i\gt k}n_i^{-1}\leqslant 1$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n$ diverges. Observe that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=n_{k}+1}^{n_{k+1}}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nT^{-i}A\right) &\geqslant \sum_{n=n_{k}+1}^{n_{k+1}}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nT^{-i}A_{k+1}\right)\\
&\geqslant \sum_{n=n_{k}+1}^{n_{k+1}}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_{k+1}}T^{-i}A_{k+1}\right)\\
&=\left(n_{k+1}-n_k\right)\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_{k+1}}T^{-i}A_{k+1}\right)\\
&\geqslant \left(n_{k+1}-n_k\right)\frac{1}{2n_{k+1}}.
\end{align}

Now, one can choose $n_k=2^km_k$, where $m_k$ is such that $16\cdot 2^{k+1}m_k^2\leqslant m_{k+1}$. In this way, 
$$16n_k^2\sum_{i\gt k}n_i^{-1} \leqslant 16\cdot 2^{2k}m_k^2\sum_{i\gt k}2^{-i}m_{k+1}^{-1}\leqslant 1.$$
Since $n_k/n_{k+1}\to 0$, the quantity $\sum_{n=n_{k}+1}^{n_{k+1}}p_n$ can be made bigger than $1/4$ for $k$ large enough.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for you answer!